# permission denied setting parameter in pgAdmin

Tags: amazon-redshift, pgadmin

I am very new to **pgAdmin**. I added a **postgres** instance running on Amazon **redshift**. After entering all the details, I get the error

```
permission denied to set parameter"client_min_messages" to "notice"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Client for Postgress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328049/sql-client-for-postgress)

Answer (score 0):

both Redshift or RDS postgres give us very limited permission. i dont think you able to change client_min_messages